# How can I sort an ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

So I'm working on a Breadth-First search function for a program I'm working on for school, and when I go through the outgoing edges for a given node, by virtue of how I'm going through my possible edges, it looks something like this:

```
[[A, 1], [D, 1], [C, 2], [D, 2]]
```

But what I really want is this:

```
[[A, 1], [C, 2], [D, 1], [D, 2]]
```

Where the first index of a pair is the name of the node that the edge points to, and the second index is the label for the edge. Essentially I want to go through these edges alphabetically, first by node name, then by label name, but I'm not sure how to do that, since Collections.sort() doesn't work for a 2D ArrayList. Any pointers/ideas on a good method to sort this? Thanks everyone!

EDIT: I am using JRE 1.7 for this assignment, not 1.8

Comment: `[[A, 1], [D, 1], [C, 2], [D, 2]]` is is not a valid example for `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` 
You could use `.stream().sorted()` to sort by natural order or even define a custom `Comparator`

Comment: You could use a HashMap instead of an ArrayList...

Comment: RoiEX, could not use HashMap since he can have a Key that has different values or has to be an HashMap<String, int[]> ... that makes a quite complicated structure for something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**here is the complete working code.** 
working with lambda expression in java SDK8.

As  you will see, I've added a simple class and a comparator. This is simple and powerful.

```
package com.rizze.test.labs.sof;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

public class SOF {    

    public static class Link {
        public String name;
        public int id;

        public static Link build(String n, int i){
            Link l = new Link();
            l.name = n;
            l.id=i;
            return l;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return String.format("[%s , %d]", name,id);
        }           
    }       

    @Test
    public void test() {

        List<Link> links = new ArrayList<Link>();

        //SSETUP [[A, 1], [C, 2], [D, 1], [D, 2]]
        links.add(Link.build("D", 1));
        links.add(Link.build("A", 1));
        links.add(Link.build("D", 2));
        links.add(Link.build("C", 2));


        Collections.sort(links, new Comparator<Link>() {    
            @Override
            public int compare(Link p1, Link p2) {
                int ret = p1.name.compareTo(p2.name);
                if(ret == 0) {
                    ret= p1.id - p2.id;
                }
                return ret;             
            }               
        });
        System.out.println(links);          
    }    
}
```

//Console output

```
Before : [[D , 1], [A , 1], [D , 2], [C , 2]]
Sorted: [[A , 1], [C , 2], [D , 1], [D , 2]]
```

//GIST link
https://gist.github.com/jeorfevre/cbcd7dac5d7fabde6a16db83bdfb7ef5

Answer (score 2):

@jeorfevre answer is perfectly ok. You didn't mention version of Java but I'd go with static `Comparator` methods.

The solution will be declarative and will give you more control and clarity in a succinct way:

```
public class Test {
    public static class Edge {
        private String name;
        private int label;
        public Edge(String name, int id) {
            this.name = name;
            this.label = id;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("[%s , %d]", name, label);
        } 
        public String getName() { return name; } 
        public int getLabel() { return label; }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<>();
        edges.add(new Edge("D", 1));
        edges.add(new Edge("A", 1));
        edges.add(new Edge("D", 2));
        edges.add(new Edge("C", 2));

        Comparator<Edge> comparator = Comparator
                .comparing(Edge::getName)
                .thenComparing(Edge::getLabel);

        edges.sort(comparator);

        System.out.println(edges);
    }
}
```

If you want reversed order:

```
            Comparator<Edge> comparator = Comparator
                .comparing(Edge::getName)
                .thenComparing(Edge::getLabel)
                .reversed();
```

Gives you:

```
[[D , 2], [D , 1], [C , 2], [A , 1]]
```

And

```
            Comparator<Edge> comparator = Comparator
                .comparing(Edge::getName)
                .reversed()
                .thenComparing(Edge::getLabel);
```

output is:
    [[D , 1], [D , 2], [C , 2], [A , 1]]

Comment: This looks great!  It's pretty much exactly what i was thinking about implementing (Edge class) and it gives me a little more perspective about how I should manage my edges.  My next question is, since I'm working with these edges not inside an Edge class, but in a completely different class, where would I put the comparator?  Would it go inside whatever function I'm currently working with? Apologies, I'm relatively new to Java and very new to comparators.

Comment: Also, I am having an issue with the commands Edge::getName and Edge::getLabel because for this assignment, my professor wants us using JRE 1.7, not 1.8.  Is there another way to implement this using JRE 1.7?